# MySQL master-master replication between database running on 3 different server

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-replication, master-master

I am trying to implement a master-master replication between 3 MySQL Databases running on 3 different servers.

I implemented master-master replication for 2 servers, but can't figure out how can I implement if for 3 different MySQL Servers.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: I have some advice.  Don't do it.  You'll regret it later.  This configuration is incredibly unstable and increases your points of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it up as a ring -- A is the master for B, B is the master for C, and C is the master for A. And don't forget to set the `log_slave_updates` option so that they will pass on upstream changes, and set `replicate-same-server-id` to 0 so that the updates won't go round and round the ring for ever.

Read [this article](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html) -- the ring configuration is described on page 2.

Comment: I used your suggestions with a few alteration and I was successful in implementing the required replication... Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to know your comments, too, on the comment posted by @Aaron? (I may post another question for the same). Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never actually used this configuration for a production service, so I can't really add anything except to point out that because it's a ring then if any one instance fails then your replication will fail globally.

Comment: ah... I understand what you say! Do you think "MySQL Cluster" can serve my purpose?